# Prove if $x$ is not equal $0$ in $V$, if $c$ not equal $0$, then $cx$ not equal to $0$

Tags: linear-algebra

I translated this to an alternative statement: if $x\neq 0$ in $V$, $cx = 0$ iff $c = 0$.

My attempt by contradiction:

$cx = 0$

$cx + 0 = 0$

$cx + cx = cx$

$2cx = cx$

But so far all I'm getting are circular statements like this, and I feel that this isn't the right direction, but I'm at a lost for what theorem to use

EDIT: so I divided $c$ from both sides,

$2cx = cx$

$2x = x$

and then say that since $x$ is not zero, this is not satisfied, which means the assumption that $cx = 0$ (leading to this conclusion is wrong) Though I still feel that this logic is quite circular.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Do a proof by contradiction. Assume that $x$ is not the zero vector, $cx$ is the zero vector, and $c$ is not zero. There's a particular property of fields that you used in your edit that is helpful here, specifically regarding multiplication.

Comment: Could you point out why my statement isn't justified?

Comment: @LtotheV Honestly, you're pretty much there after the edit, but you need to talk about the multiplicative identity. If $2x=x$, then $2x-x=1x=0$. Then because we have a multiplicative identity, we must have $x=0$. You also skip over the assumption that $c$ is nonzero, which is why you can divide by $c$ in the first place.

Comment: In that case, could I say since 2x = x, then -x is the additive inverse of 2x, but we know that cx + 0 = cx, thus 0 is the additive identity in this case, and 2x - x = 1x, and 1x isn't 0, thus leading to a contradiction?

Comment: "but we know that cx + 0 = cx, thus 0 is the additive identity in this case" Everything else you said makes sense (same as my comment), but I don't see why you need this line.